# Build a linear plane, approximating the input points

Tags: matlab, plot, surface

It is necessary to build a graphic of linear regression based on the two criteria (characteristics). I found the values of the coefficients of the equation for a straight line in space, but not know how to build a plane using them. I tried to use "plot" function but it was a problem with the size (dimension) of the matrix.

```
data = load('mydata.txt');
X1 = data(:, 1); X2 = data(:, 2); Y = X+2.*Y;

theta0 = 0;
theta1 = 0;
theta2 = 0;

%some calculations for all of theta....

x = min(X1):0.1:max(X1);
y = min(X2):0.1:max(X2);
z = theta0 + theta1*x + theta2*y;

plot(x,y,z);
```

Comment: You want to use a 3d plot tool, like [mplot3d](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
[x, y] = meshgrid(min(X):0.1:max(X), min(Y):0.1:max(Y));
z = curT0 + curT1*x + curT2*y;
mesh(x,y,z);     %surface
hold all;
scatter3(X,Y,Z); %points
hold off;
```

Thanks to all who have thought about my question.